# How to sum the value of dynamically created textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to sum the value of dynamically created `textbox`, but it doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".code").each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".code").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

function addrow() {
  $("#customFields").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="ename" id="name" placeholder="Expense Name"/> &nbsp;</td>                                    <td><input type="text" class="code" id="code" placeholder="Amount"/> &nbsp;</td> </tr>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="customFields">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addrow();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want. When and how do you want the even generated?

Comment: I suppose you need a #sum element?

Comment: i also have #sum element                                                                              
<tr valign="top">
      <tr id="summation">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td align="right">Sum :</td>
  <td align="center"><span id="sum">0</span></td>
 </tr>

Comment: Yeah a lot of code is simply incorrect.  Please take another round at your code and edit your question when you have something closer to your stated problem.

Comment: i want to show the total sum when anyone type the value in textbox .

Comment: please help me to find my incorrect code.. i am new to javascript

Comment: @arif You have missed `class="code"` on the newly added textfields

Comment: it already shown class="code" in my inspect element  when i add new dynamic textbox

Comment: @K3v1n there is `class="code"` on the input field. Maybe you missed it because all of the whitespace in the OP's question, but it's there. Also there is an `id="code"` which is invalid (can't have multiple elements with the same ID) but that's another matter...

Comment: @PatrickMoore ah yes, it was the whitespace

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.on()` on the table, which allows interaction with new dynamically-created elements. This will allow all `keyup` from all `.code` (even those added after page load) to bubble up to `#customFields`. The rest of your code should not need to be altered.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#customFields").on( "keyup", ".code", function(){
      calculateSum();
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @arif click on the gray tick mark on the left side of the answer to mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: clicked...@K3v1n

Answer (score -1):

Please see the 
[Running Code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFIGBKEAWWNH)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  //iterate through each textboxes and add keyup
  //handler to trigger sum event
  $(".code").each(function() {

    $(this).keyup(function() {
      calculateSum();
    });
  });

});

function calculateSum() {

  var sum = 0;
  //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
  $(".code").each(function() {

    //add only if the value is number
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }

  });
  //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places

  $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
}

function addrow() {
  $("#customFields").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="ename" id="name" placeholder="Expense Name"/> &nbsp;</td>                                          <td><input type="text" class="code" id="code" placeholder="Amount" onKeyUp = "calculateSum()"/> &nbsp;</td> </tr>');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id="customFields">
  <tr>
    <td colspan ="2">
      <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addrow();" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td><div id="sum">value</div></td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but you write in your code. don't mind i am asking too many question